# Python convert type hint string representation (from docstring) to actual type/typing object

Tags: python, type-hinting, docstring

I would like to know if there is an existing implementation that converts the string representation of a type hint (e.g. from a docstring) back to the type (or typing) object. Thereby arbitrary deep nested types should also be supported (see third example).

```py
import typing import List, Optional, Union

converter_function("List[str]") == List[str]

converter_function("int") == int

converter_function("Optional[List[Union[str, float]]]") == Optional[List[Union[str,float]]]

converter_function("foobar") # Exception / None
```

One option would be to simply use eval, but I would like to avoid that at all costs :D

**Edit**
As background on why I want to do this: I want to write a script that checks if a docstring matches 100% to a function, all types are correct and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is such a thing but I'm curious about the reason you needed it. Do you have a concrete example or use case? @g3n35i5

Comment: @KutayAslan I have updated my question and hopefully answered your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I can find (except for `eval` of course) is `typing.get_type_hints`. If your functions are properly type annotated, then `typing.get_type_hints` can resolve the annotations. It works for string annotations, arbitrarily nested types, and generic types; basically any valid annotations. For example:

```
from typing import List, Optional, Union, get_type_hints

def my_func(a: "List[str]", b: "int") -> "Optional[List[Union[str, float]]]":
    pass

print(get_type_hints(my_func))
```

you'd get

```
{'a': typing.List[str],
 'b': <class 'int'>,
 'return': typing.Optional[typing.List[typing.Union[str, float]]]}
```

Internally, `get_type_hints` converts the strings into `typing.ForwardRef`s and then evaluate them. These are private APIs so they might not be stable across Python versions, but if you only have the annotation strings but not a function, you might try this out:

```
>>> from typing import ForwardRef, _eval_type

>>> _eval_type(ForwardRef("Optional[List[Union[str, float]]]"), globals(), globals())
typing.Optional[typing.List[typing.Union[str, float]]]
```

but at this point, you might be better off with `eval` :P

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your answer. I think I have to accept that the API may not be stable. The alternative "eval" will certainly hurt more :D